# String Matching from List of items

Tags: r, string, match

Updating my question asked, I have an object search_string that stores the string.

```
> search_string
```

[1] "Bud Light - Mother EUR"

I have an another object of list that stores the Brand Names and Zone Names. Now using the search_string, i search it in the filter_values and returns what was year and what was Brand Name. I use the below command to achieve that.

```
> lapply(filter_values, function(x) {
    +       x[sapply(paste0('\\b',x,'\\b'), grepl,input$param$query, ignore.case=T)]
    +     
    +     })
$Brand
[1] "Bud Light"          "Bud Light - Mother"

$Zone
[1] "EUR"
```

Now, issue i am facing is that if u notice in the output returned, searching for **Bud Light - Mother**
in the list also returns **Bud Light** which is not required. 
How can i restrict it to return only what is entered/asked and not the closest matches also like returned right now.

Answer (score 3):

An idea is to strip the `search_string` from the Year and match the Brand and vice versa, i.e.

```
Map(function(x, y) grep(x, y, value = TRUE), 
         c(trimws(gsub('[0-9]{4}', '', search_string)), gsub('\\D+', '', search_string)), 
         filter_values)

#$`Bud Light - Mother`
#[1] "Bud Light - Mother"

#$`2014`
#[1] "2014"
```

Same result can be achieved by using `strsplit` as per @Cath's comment,

```
Map(function(x, y) grep(x, y, value = TRUE), 
    strsplit(search_string, "\\s(?=\\d{4})", perl=TRUE)[[1]], 
    filter_values)
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick and effective answer but the constraint we have here is that we cant take any particular action on Year or Brand while searching as the list of filter values will be dynamic and might not contains Year but something else later. Search has to be dynamic.

Comment: instead of `c(trimws(gsub('[0-9]{4}', '', search_string)), gsub('\\D+', '', search_string))` you can use `strsplit(search_string, "\\s(?=\\d{4})", perl=TRUE)[[1]]` ;-)

Comment: @RishabAsthana If you have any limitations you need to update your question with them

Comment: @Cath on updating the command, to this                    lapply(filter_values, function(x) {
      x[sapply(paste0('\\b',x,'\\b'), grepl,strsplit(search_string, "\\s(?=\\d{4})", perl=TRUE)[[1]], ignore.case=T)]
    
    })                                                                                                            
  It returns this $Brand
**[1] "Bud Light" NA**         

$Year
[1] "2015"                                                                                                
 But it should be **"Bud Light - Mother"**  in the Brand. Returning NA in brand name.